# Use array values as constant

Tags: javascript

how can I use array values as constant like ; aaa 500,bbb 350,ccc 25 and at last calc value 1725.

```js
const vals = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];
clength = vals.length;
i=0;
while (i < clength)
{
vals[i] = document.getElementById(vals[i]).value;
i=i+1
};

document.getElementById("calc").value = (aaa + bbb)*2 + ccc;
```

```html
<input id="aaa" value="500">
<input id="bbb" value="350">
<input id="ccc" value="25">
<br>
<br>

<br>

<input id="calc">
```

how can I use array values as constant like ;
aaa 500,bbb 350,ccc 25 and at last calc value  1725.

I want while loop behave like ;

> aaa = 500; bbb= 350; ccc = 25;

NOTE : Please think array function as endless.(aaa,bbb,ccc is just samples)

Comment: Hi I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. Do you want to declare key value pairs, like aaa corresponds to 500 etc? You have objects for that.

Comment: I will explain it on question... Edit

Comment: Why do you push the values into array if you don't ever use them?

Comment: I took those value from mysql with array tag than I need to use them in javascript like that...

Comment: OK but how would you know which values to add and which to multiply? Is length of that array always the same?

Answer (score 1):

There's many ways to do it but without changing your code much you could use a desctructive assignment:

```
const [aaa, bbb, ccc] = vals;
document.getElementById("calc").value = (aaa + bbb)*2 + ccc;
```

It would be better to use a key/value pairs though:

```js
document.getElementById('calc').value = calc(resolveCalcValues());


function calc(vals) {
  return (vals.aaa + vals.bbb) * 2 + vals.ccc;
}

function resolveCalcValues() {
  return valuesOf('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
}

function valuesOf(...inputIds) {
  return inputIds.reduce((vals, id) => {
    vals[id] = document.getElementById(id).value;
    return vals;
  }, {});
}
```

```html
<input id="aaa" type="number" value="500">
<input id="bbb" type="number" value="350">
<input id="ccc" type="number" value="25">

<input id="calc">
```

Comment: how did you take 500, 350 and 25 by the way?

Comment: Well your original code did put the values of those in the `vals` array and then you extract those values into constants with the destructive assignment.

Comment: but the problem is that : that is not only aaa,bbb,ccc it changs all the time so it must be more generally code

Comment: Well, do you have a way to write the `calc` function in a generic way? If not then you must know how values are treated in the calculation anyway. For instance, if you just add `'ddd'` don't you have to adjust the calculation function?

Comment: @May Consider accepting if you choose that path.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create variables through the `window` object and remember to convert strings to number to calculate with them:

```js
const vals = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"];

for (const val of vals) {
  window[val] = +document.getElementById(val).value;
}

document.getElementById("calc").value = (aaa + bbb)*2 + ccc;
```

```html
<input id="aaa" value="500">
<input id="bbb" value="350">
<input id="ccc" value="25">
<br>
<br>

<br>

<input id="calc">
```

Comment: Polluting `window` is not a good modern practice

Comment: @charlietfl But that's the question. OP want's to use variables `aaa`, `bbb` and `ccc`.

Comment: Fine but that doesn't mean using window is a good idea

Comment: @charlietfl You can post an alternative approach. This is my understanding of the question and IMHO the best approach to solve this if you want to read the variable names from a string array.

Comment: what you prefer in spite of window?

Comment: @charlietfl yes please if you have better idea please share it with us... or I will upvote this answer

Comment: @May A separate object would be better and would prevent possible collisions in window object. `const obj ={}`....  In loop `obj[val] = ...`

Comment: What's being overlooked here overall is that the entire logic block shouldn't just execute in the global context. The window-based solution is not composable and you can't encapsulate the logic properly without bleeding into the global context where you could with the approach I suggested which is similar to what @charlietfl has proposed.

Comment: The other problem is you are hard coding the `aaa` , `bbb` etc so it assumes those are the same values in the array which OP has stated they are variable

Comment: thanks for answer.. a little more I need to ask with that way :  what if "<input id ="input_1" value="(aaa + bbb)*2 + ccc"> how can I use that also inside that code window didnt work properly for that

Answer (score 0):

Following is a more generic approach based on adding different class names to the inputs server side and doesn't involve using any ID or variables at all

```js
function collectionSum (selector){
   const els =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))
   return els.reduce((a,c) => a + Number(c.value),0);
}

const combined = collectionSum('.values.combine'),
      add = collectionSum('.values.add');
      

document.getElementById("calc").value = combined * 2 + add;
```

```html
<input class="values combine" id="aaa" value="500">
<input class="values combine" id="bbb" value="350">
<input class="values add" id="ccc" value="25">
<br>
<br>

<br>

<input id="calc">
```